# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; when inserting data into SQL database through JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I am designing a JFrame where I will accept data for Name, Username, Password, Phone, No. and an image location 'img' from a JFileChooser. Impractically, I am inserting passwords without hashing and the Phone No. column has data type as VarChar(45). That should be overlooked as I am pretty new to SQL programming using JAVA.

The Sign-Up button is used to insert data into an SQL row. The ActionListener is as follows:

```
signupbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try
                {
                    Statement st=conn.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs=null;
                    String name=namef.getText(),usnm=usnmf.getText(),pswd=pswdf.getText(),ph=phf.getText();
                    String sql="insert into data (name,username,password,ph.no.,profile) values("+name+","+usnm+","+pswd+","+ph+","+img+")";
                    st.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                    int key = 0;
                    rs = st.getGeneratedKeys();
                    if (rs.next()) 
                    {
                        key = rs.getInt(1);
                    }
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Key : "+key);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        });
```

When the data is given and the button is clicked, an Exception is catched and printed:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',profile) values(Jyotirmay,Usnm,Pswd,1122334455,E:\1.jpg' at line 1
```

Why is the error showing up? I have tried several methods like using `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` with `?` but still getting the error.

**P.S.**

Using PreparedStatement:

```
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try
                {
                    String sql="INSERT into data (name, username, password, ph.no., profile) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
                    PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    String name=namef.getText(),usnm=usnmf.getText(),pswd=pswdf.getText(),ph=phf.getText();
                    st.setString(1, name);
                    st.setString(2, usnm);
                    st.setString(3, pswd);
                    st.setString(4, ph);
                    st.setString(5, img);
                    st.executeUpdate();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SUCESS! Data inserted. Try Logging In.");

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Note: img is already declared and initialised. Also, the asolute image location is correctly printed in the console.**

Comment: Assuming all the table fields are string (TEXT, VARCHAR, etc): `String sql = "INSERT into data (name, username, password, ph.no., profile) VALUES ('" + name + "','" + usnm + "','" + pswd + "','" + ph + "','" + img + "');";` [Read This](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

Comment: @DevilsHnd Thanks for your response but it surely didn't work and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Well then...Where is **img** declared and supplied a String? You will need that **as well** since you have it in your SQL statement. :)

Comment: @DevilsHnd 'img' is declared in the class body and data is given in the ActionListener using a JFileChooser. After choosing the file, it's absolute path is also printed correctly in the console (Eclipse).

Comment: You will definitely want to use `PreparedStatements`, as this code leaves you open for SQL injections. You said you tried it with `PreparedStatements` already, can you post that code?

Comment: Strings should be enclose within apostrophes ( **'My String'** ).

Comment: @Seeseemelk I've added the code using PreparedStatement but still getting the error.

Comment: you can not write a column name such as `ph.no.` without quoted within the column list of the insert statement.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the table field name `ph.no.`. Enclose all field names in apostrophes as well.

Comment: `String sql = "INSERT INTO data ('name', 'username', 'password', 'ph.no.', 'profile') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a dot in a column name without escaping it.
It's probably best to rename the column so it is not using dots anymore, although you can also try to use backticks in the column name like this:

```java
btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try
                {
                    String sql="INSERT into data (name, username, password, `ph.no.`, profile) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
                    PreparedStatement st=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    String name=namef.getText(),usnm=usnmf.getText(),pswd=pswdf.getText(),ph=phf.getText();
                    st.setString(1, name);
                    st.setString(2, usnm);
                    st.setString(3, pswd);
                    st.setString(4, ph);
                    st.setString(5, img);
                    st.executeUpdate();

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SUCESS! Data inserted. Try Logging In.");

                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        });
```